# How do I convert SCTE35 cue marker from JSON to binary?

Tags: json, binary, mpeg-dash, scte-35

I am working on MPEG DASH and have SCTE35 binary cue Events that look something like this.

```
<Event id="6" presentationTime="50726727">
    <scte35:signal>
        <scte35:binary>/DBhAAAAAAAA///wBQb+qM1E7QBLAhdDVUVJSAAArX+fCAgAAAAALLLXnTUCAAIXQ1VFSUgAACZ/nwgIAAAAACyy150RAAACF0NVRUlIAAAnf58ICAAAAAAsstezEAAAihiGnw==</scte35:binary>
    </scte35:signal>
</Event>
```

If decoded using [https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/Cue?cue=/DBhAAAAAAAA///wBQb+qM1E7QBLAhdDVUVJSAAArX+fCAgAAAAALLLXnTUCAAIXQ1VFSUgAACZ/nwgIAAAAACyy150RAAACF0NVRUlIAAAnf58ICAAAAAAsstezEAAAihiGnw==](https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/Cue?cue=/DBhAAAAAAAA///wBQb%20qM1E7QBLAhdDVUVJSAAArX%20fCAgAAAAALLLXnTUCAAIXQ1VFSUgAACZ/nwgIAAAAACyy150RAAACF0NVRUlIAAAnf58ICAAAAAAsstezEAAAihiGnw==) it returns a SpliceInfoSection JSON Object. I want to be able to make changes to the JSON and convert it back to binary format for testing purposes.

Any help would be appreciated.